# Symfony clear cache memory limit

Tags: php, symfony, caching

Here's my problem: when I try to execute the cache:clear command in my dev environment, I have a fatal error because of the PHP memory limit. So, I tried to increase this limit to 2048M, which should be enough, but still the same issue.

I tried everything: manually deleting the cache folder before executing the command, set the PHP memory_limit to -1 (stopped by Windows because it was out of memory to allocate), executing the command with --no-warmup or --no-optional-warmers...

For information, everything else works like a charm...

Why this command is so greedy? And how can I solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where did you change the memory limit.

There is a big chance your `php.ini` is different for web server and command line Interface(CLI).

If you face the problem of `memory limit` in command line, make sure you are edit the correct `php.ini` file.

To know what are the `ini` files are in used. run the command : `php --ini`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I change the memory limit, I can see that it's taken into account because when I put 256M, it fails at 256M, when I put 512M, it fails at 512M, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when I was upgrading from SF2.3 to SF2.8 (lot of BC changes). 
PHP scripts run via CLI doesn't have max memory restriction set by default. That is why all memory resources are being used up.

Problem went away after I:

1. upgraded bundles to more recent version, which were probably not compatible enough with recent SF version at the time.
2. Fixed all my code to reflect BC changes from upgrade manual (mostly form types, yaml settings and controllers).

Bundles and my code were producing a lot more debug information (usually deprecation warnings), which caused PHP Xdebug to take up all the resources until memory maxed out. I noticed that only while warming up cache. After all the fixes I kept warning messages to minimum.

You could check:

- dev.log for any deprecation warnings
- xdebug settings and set max_nesting_level to some sane value:
  *xdebug.max_nesting_level=1200*
- disable xdebug for CLI, which is unnecessary anyway:
     *php5dismod -s cli xdebug*

Comment: Hi, I've checked the dev.log, it seems ok. In my CLI php.ini file, the XDebug is disabled... Still the same issue! Thanks for your answer.